# How to make table to keep the size of container

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm trying to create a popup window with table inside and can't make table to keep the size of container. I don't want to use setHeight() method for table because another "skin" can require another value for height.

Playground example is here http://tinyurl.com/l4oro2z

Don't you have any idea?

Comment: What about using a percentage?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for having disturbed you, but finally I have found how to fix this layout issue.
If you are interested in here is fixed example http://tinyurl.com/n23wfnm

changes are in lines 47 and 62

Comment: Idomatic solution. I think the crucial point is adding the table with flex:1 to the container.